# Bugzilla is not sending out emails

Tags: apache-2.2, email, smtp, installation, bugzilla

Hi I'm pretty new at this and I'd like to ask how to debug any of my installations. Bugzilla doesn't seem to be sending out emails. If i set the delivery method to 'test' a mailer.testfile is successfully generated. However when i set it to 'smtp' no emails are ever received by the intended recepients. I also am not sure which files to attach here so if anyone needs anything to be pasted just tell me and i'll post it asap. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: by the way i am using postfix smtp. apache webserver and CentOs 6.3

Comment: Is there any information in your mail server logs (on the server that is set as the SMTP server)

Answer (score 2):

There is params file for bugzilla configuration you need to provide this configuration option:
'mail_delivery_method' = > 'Sendmail'.
Your server where you host your bugzilla installation needs to be configured to be able to forward/relay the emails to your smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

If you set mail_delivery_method to "SMTP", then you need to set the details (server name, and perhaps login and password) for the SMTP server you want to use elsewhere on that preferences pane. Did you do that? If you did, then you need to make sure that your Bugzilla machine can see and is permitted to pass mail to the SMTP server. Try telnetting to it on port 25 from the Bugzilla machine, as a quick test.

If you set mail_delivery_method to "Sendmail" rather than "SMTP", then it will use a local installation of sendmail, which itself has to be configured correctly. But how to do that is not a Bugzilla question :-)

Gerv